# 2 same netowork printers in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, printing, canon

I wanted to install my Pixma TS6052 as a network printer. I have installed Canon drivers for my Pixma TS6052. Now when I see in my Kubuntu 20.04 2 Canon Pixma TS6000 series network printers there. They were added automatically by Kubuntu. It is nice from Ubuntu to discover my network printers, but I do not want them to be installed automatically. When I try to remove them they stay and don't go.

How can I remove them or at least leave ony one?

Comment: just delete the one from printers list you want to delete. It is like that only.

Comment: I wrote above: "When I try to remove them they stay and don't go."

Comment: If you have more than one computer on the network then it may be sharing that printer. If they are the same OS then they will auto configure with the same name.  I recommend all Canon printers be configured with System Settings.  GutenPrint does the job well.

Comment: I have only 1 printer, but I noticed that the printer is removed only after a reboot. It is a bit werid

Comment: "A bit weird"  Welcome to the world of open source computing :)  Its an adventure.

Comment: The second automatic printer from Kubuntu is back again. And it is not shared. Everytime I remove it it comes back. It seems to be a Kubuntu bug (?).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend letting Kubuntu add the printer. Then when its done you add another one with your name and all the details you want. Test it from an application and from the print test page.  Then delete the printer you don't want. You can add the same printer with different details as many times as you want. If another one keeps coming back then you may have a network loop.  Another printer is sharing your printer back to you. [image]

Comment: the hint with the network loop sounds ood. I will check it. thank you!!!

Comment: The second automatic printer from Kubuntu is back. And it is not shared. Everytime I remove it it comes back. It seems to be a bug. So this answer does not help.

Comment: I have upgraded all my machines to 20.04 Kubuntu.  Loving it but the printers are doing the same thing.  I can't seem to stop them.  BUT I will win in the end and report back.